# SonarLint : Code smell : Rename this file to

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, sonarlint

After analyzing my code with SonarLint, I get the following smell code: **Rename this file to "Notify"**.

I tried to change the name of my component several times but I still get the code smell.

path : **alert-toast.tsx**

here is my component :

```
import { Slide, toast } from 'react-toastify';

const Notify = (type: string, message: any) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'warning':
    return toast.warning(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
case 'error':
  return toast.error(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
case 'success':
  return toast.success(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
case 'info':
  return toast.info(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
case 'dark':
  return toast.dark(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
default:
  return toast(message, {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    transition: Slide,
    closeOnClick: true,
    closeButton: false,
    theme: 'colored',
  });
 }
};
export default Notify;
```

Is there a solution to avoid this smell code ?

Comment: The message says "rename this file", not "rename this component".  The point of the warning is that the filename should be the same as the component it contains: right now you have `Notify` contained in `alert-toast.jsx`. Make them match.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks ! indeed the name of the component was not the same as the tsx file